# Prove that $f(\Bbb C)=\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need some help with the following problem:

> Let $f:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ be continuous satisfying that $f(\Bbb C)$ is an open set and that $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $z\to \infty$. Prove that $f(\Bbb C)=\Bbb C$.

My idea on this one is to prove by contradiction and assume that $S=f(\Bbb C)\ne\Bbb C$ to get some contradiction with the given two properties of the function. But I have no idea on how to proceed next.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see $C\cup\{\infty\}=S^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your condition, the image of $f$ is closed (why? take a convergent sequence of points in the image, and their preimages. The preimages do not diverge to infinity, by assumption, so they have a limit point, which, by continuity, goes to the limit you want). So, $f(\mathbb{C})$ is open (by assumption) and closed. So, since $\mathbb{C}$ is connected, the image is all of $\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: Without using the condition about the unboundedness?

Comment: You need to use it to show closedness.

Comment: Show closedness by using that condition? That sounds a little strange to me.

Comment: @Scorpio19891119 read the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $w$ is in the boundary of $f(\mathbb C)$.  Take a sequence $z_n$ with $f(z_n) \to w$.  There is a subsequence ...

Comment: What is "boundary"?

Comment: I presume he means a point of $\operatorname{Clos}(f(\mathbb{C})) - f(\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions imply that we can *continuously extend* $f$ to give a continuous function $\hat{f}$ from the Riemann sphere to itself given below

$$ \hat{f}(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) & x \neq \infty \\ \infty & x = \infty \end{cases}$$

Comment: What about this function?